# Laravel - Check wether an account is active or not

Tags: laravel, validation, authentication, controller

I have a "user" table that has an attribute named "active" which is set to boolean. So it only accept values true/false or 1/0.

But my code here doesn't seem to do the work;

```
if(Auth::user()->active == 1){

    if(Auth::user()->user_level === 'Administrator'){

        return view('admin.home');

    } else {

        return view('user.home');

    }

} else {

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I cannot log in active accounts with that first condition, but when I change it to 0, every account works even tho it's inactive.

Comment: Are you sure the user has logged in? Use `dd(Auth::user());` to check if the user logged in firstly.

Comment: @MichaelChen I'm kinda confused on how to use this. I tried returning that but it's giving me a json thingy

Comment: You can use it like this: `@php  dd(Auth::user()); @endphp`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(Auth::user()) { //checking if the user is logged in..
if(Auth::user()->active == 1)
{
    if(Auth::user()->user_level === 'Administrator')
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }

    else
    {
        return view('user.home');
    }
}

else
{
    return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it, didn't change anything tho.

Comment: Use `dd(Auth::user());` and update the resulting array in your question so that we can review it.